# Customize dialog while removing account from accountmanager android

Tags: android, accountmanager, android-account

I would like to prevent user from removing the account from the Android accounts for my app. Android `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` provides a method `getAccountRemovalAllowed` which I can use to prevent from removing account. So far so good.

But when I try to remove the account from settings, the dialog is scary. Says you can only remove by doing a factory reset. I would like to customize it saying you should uninstall the app to remove the account. Is there any way to do that?

I tried providing `KEY_INTENT` with my own activity but no effect.

```
public Bundle getAccountRemovalAllowed(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
        Account account) throws NetworkErrorException {
    // Cannot remove the account.
    final Bundle result = new Bundle();
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, MyDialog.class);
    result.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, i);
    return result;
}
```